# How to create and view dataset in javascript

Tags: javascript, dataset

I am a new learner of javascript. I am wondering how to generate a dataset with 3 columns and 100 rows in javascript. I need the first column named "column1", with id from 1 to 100, second column named "column2" with numbers from 100 to 200 with mean of 120, third column named "column3" with numbers from 200 to 300 with mean of 280 and also standard deviation of 15. And how do I view the dataset? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to organize a dateset of 3 columns. I composed one using object. For random numbers, I'm using d3 to generate random numbers that follow normal distribution. I'm also assuming that the standard deviation for column 2 is 15. Please see the following code snippet:

```
var column2Func = d3.random.normal(120, 15);
var column3Func = d3.random.normal(280, 15);

var res = {
  column1: [],
  column2: [],
  column3: []
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  res.column1.push(i+1);
  res.column2.push(column2Func());
  res.column3.push(column3Func());
}

console.log(res);
```

The entire code is available at http://jsbin.com/cerilugevo/edit?html,js,console

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Yu! How do I constrain the data? I only want the column3 between 200 to 300.

Comment: This should be apparent to figure out. Try experiment something in the for loop.